# How to Cold Boot Emulators Running API 27+ on Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, boot, android-virtual-device

While working with emulators in Android Studio, I prefer to have them always cold-boot because:

1) I like it when the emulator window closes immediately after clicking "X-close" rather than beginning a new "saving state" procedure.

2) I find that many-a-bugaboo occurs when returning to a "saved state" with these emulators (connection timeout on bootup, weird graphics behavior, loss of logcat connection, garbled data retrieved from shared prefs)

So... what I have always done is to go into AVD manager and change the settings like this:

[image]

However, when I attempt this with an emulator running API 27 or higher:

[image]

...there appears to be no cold boot option:

[image]

I have googled to try to find how to configure cold boot on these newer API emulators but can't find anything.

Is it possible to cold boot emulators running API 27+ on Android Studio?

Comment: Do you have an option of  `Cold Boot Now` in AVD manager when you click on an arrow next to the settings button?

Comment: Nope.  Android Studio 3.1.2 on mac.

Comment: I have a Mac too, I'll see if I have it

Comment: Can't you shut down your AVD when you're done with it? When you need to use it again, it will cold boot.

Comment: Wanted to get back to you because I finally checked with Android Studio 3.1 having the same emulator that you mentioned API 27. It's true there is no **Cold Boot** in Settings, but in the AVD manager, where all Emulators are listed, if I click on the arrow button which is next to the settings (pencil button) I have an option of **Cold Boot Now**.

Comment: Thanks for getting back.  That's wierd, mine just starts without asking me anything.

Comment: And when you click on the arrow which options do you have?

Comment: None, it just starts the emulator without asking anything. :S

Comment: Oh crap I'm sorry I realized you meant the down arrow... not "play" arrow. DERP!  Thanks!

Comment: no problem :) glad I could help :) good luck!

Answer (score 16):

Change config in:

%path_to_home%/.android/avd/%your_avd_image%/config.ini

Instead of

```
fastboot.forceColdBoot=no
```

you should set

```
fastboot.forceColdBoot=yes
```

Comment: Adding to Max's Solution,path of config.ini is changed.Please find below path where we can find config file.

C:\Users\**YourName**\.android\avd\"Select your AVD"      
                                                      
After going to above path, we can see config.ini file.Right click and open with notepad++ and search for below parameter and change it to yes.

fastboot.forceColdBoot=yes

Answer (score 0):

You can find the option if you show advance settings and scroll down. It is in the section: "Emulated Performance"